# Writing a driver for Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, driver, specifications

I am looking into writing a driver for Postgres. I've searched around and I can't seem to find the spec for the protocol that the driver would have to implement. Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: to answer my question is this the one https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol.html ?

Comment: Once again the documentation saves the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frontend/backend protocol (a.k.a “line protocol”) is documented in great detail in [chapter 52 of the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol.html).